# JAXB XML any element strict object creation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="row">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:any processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Generated Java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "row", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class ReportRowType {

    @XmlAnyElement
    protected List<Element> any;

    ...
}
```

How would I properly create an XML `org.w3c.dom.Element` to put in here? Do I just create a random document? That seems not right to me:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();
Element e = doc.createElement("random_tag_name");
row.getAny().add(e)?
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Yeah it works, it just seems a little strange to me that I can't use ObjectFactor or something.

Comment: `@XmlAnyElement` is a step towards DOM world, so there's nothing strange in using DOM API to fill it.